# Rewrite The Display of a Field in the wagtail admin edit view

Tags: wagtail, code-snippets, wagtail-snippet

I have the following model in a wagtail app:

```
class JoinusRegistration(models.Model):
    user_info = models.ForeignKey('JoinusUserFormBuilder', default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.ForeignKey('JoinusEvent', default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    wait_list = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    def name(self):
        user_info = str(self.user_info).replace("'", '"')
        json_loads = json.loads(user_info)
        return json_loads['your_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Event Registration"
```

And the following SnippetViewSet in a wagtail_hooks.py file:

```
class JoinusRegistrationAdmin(SnippetViewSet):
    model = JoinusRegistration
    menu_label = 'Registrations' 
    icon = 'doc-full'
    base_url_path = 'reg'
    list_display = ('name', 'event_name', 'registration_date' ,'wait_list')
    filterset_class = FilterByEvent
    edit_view_class = JoinusRegistrationEditView
```

On the index view of the admin, I'm able to create a custom display for the user_info field (necessary because user_info is form data saved as JSON) by creating a function called name, and adding it the list_display tuple of the SnippetViewSet. It looks like this:

[image: index view with a parsed user_infor field]

Is there any way to re-rewrite the user_info field in the edit view? The default behavior is less than ideal:

[image: edit view of the user_info field, unparsed]

I tried writing my own custom edit_view_class but could not get anything to work. EX:

```
class JoinusRegistrationEditView(EditView):
    def show_me_something(self):
        show_id = self.user_info.objects.id
        return show_id`
```